VSC debugger fails to import my own project modules in a Dev Container even when the script can be run from VSC terminal
I have a python project in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I have a DevContainer in VSC with Debian GNU/Linux 11, and If I run the application from the terminal with streamlit run myfile.py, it runs perfectly, but launching the debugger raises this exception:
/usr/bin/python3: No module named streamlit

This is my devcontainer.json:
{
    "build": {"dockerfile": "Dockerfile"},
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python",
                "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
            ]
        },
        "forwardPorts": [8501],
        "runArgs": ["--env-file",".devcontainer/devcontainer.env"]
    }
}

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install oscrypto@git+https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto.git@d5f3437ed24257895ae1edd9e503cfb352e635a8

# COPY src ./src
# WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH=/workspaces/my_project/src

EXPOSE 8001
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "view/frontend/main.py"]

And this is my launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"}
        },
        {
            "name": "Python:Streamlit",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "${file}",
                "--server.port",
                "8501",
                "--server.fileWatcherType",
                "poll",
                "--server.address",
                "0.0.0.0"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
                "PYTHONHOME": "/usr/local/bin"
            }
        }
    ]
}

What else do I have to set up for VSC Debugger to work properly?
